# How to get the news having comments?

Tags: sql

I want to get the news that have comments with order of total comments,

I try to this SQL code

```
SELECT COUNT( comment ) , N . * , C . * 
FROM news N, comment C
WHERE N.ID = C.ID_NEWS
```

but the problem it's return just the first news with total of all comments

is there any solution ?

Comment: First, pretty please don't use old comma-syntax for joining two tables. Look at proper `JOIN` types. Second, what is your DBMS?

Comment: Depending on your DBMS, you usually have to include each column you list in your `SELECT` in your `GROUP BY`. Do you want to `SELECT *` from both tables?

Comment: That statement should not return anything as it is invalid SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a query like this :

```
SELECT N.ID as comments_order, 
       count( C.comment ) as total_comments
  FROM news N INNER JOIN comment C
    ON (  N.ID = C.ID_NEWS )
 GROUP BY N.ID
 ORDER BY total_comments;
```

Comment: It's work but I want to make order by totalcomments `COUNT( C.comment )`

Comment: @ThaSayou try to use `ORDER BY count( C.comment )`

Comment: @Shawn exactly, that's also possible and better thanks.

Comment: Also, it looks like OP wants order to be `DESC` by the most comments.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan True. My assumption was that the OP wanted the news sorted by most comments to fewest. The question wasn't worded as well as it could be. :-)